# CSS overflow content when container < window height

Tags: css, window, overflow, containers

On [this link](http://dev.justrightwebdesign.nl/proj/index.html) I've build a simple html/css based layout. What I want to achieve the following: I want that the content section gets a overflow-y as soon the window height is smaller then the content height. The footer and header need to stay in the same position. Only the content section must be smaller.

This sounds very simple, but to my own surprise I couldn't find a solution yet. I'll tried to add some max-/min-height and overflow values to the content section, but this wouldn't work.

Would be awesome if someone could help me out. Thanks

Comment: Can javascript/jquery be used or is this css/html only?

Comment: If necessary, js can be used of course

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of CSS and jQuery addClass() as follows (I am calling the content section #Content, let's say 600px for this post):

```
//css
#Content {
height:600px;
//etc.
}
.contentoverflow {
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Now on page load, add an onload function to the body (note that the Content div lacks any classes):

```
<body onload="checkHeight()">
<div id="Content">

<!--Your content goes here-->

</div>
```

Now the JavaScript / jQuery:

```
function checkHeight() {
    var scr = screen.availHeight;
    var contentHeight = 600; //or whatever number you choose)
    if (contentHeight > scr) {
        $("#Content").addClass("contentoverflow");
    }
}
```